# How do criminals access dark web from their home internet, which is payed for in their name, without enabling NSA/FBI to disclose their real identity?

Tags: darknet

Is Tor, VPN, obfuscated bridges, MAC spoofing and Qubes-Whonix enough to prevent the government from tracing them to their ISP, who can give out their information? Is it safe to do so from home? Do these kinds of people instead use public wifi? Is it still possible to be tracked down when using a public wifi? (I.e. is one completely anonymous if one successfully manages to conceal one's IP (and possibly MAC)?)

Comment: You have a lot of questions rolled into one. And this is almost a direct duplicate of your other question.

Comment: @schroeder Yeah, I lost my email to my previous account, and I spent an entire day trying to get my account back, so I set up another account and posted this question. It is not the same question; I just wonder how notorious people (DPR, Sabu, Yardbird e.g.) could access the DW from home without getting caught, or if they used a public wifi. What tools did they use to not get caught if they used internet connection payed for in their name to do illegal stuff? Is VPN+Tor+obfs4+MAC spoof enough, and if so, how, approximately, did their setup look? (Also, idk if MAC spoofing matters for anonymity

Comment: They do not use their home internet. They use other people's internet. Public wifi if there are no cameras to correlate the network activity with physical presence.

Comment: @schroeder Are the tools I mentioned enough, then? What would the ideal and most anonymous setup look like? (Which tools and in which order)

Comment: I really can't get into that here. There are tons of different things to consider and they are all discussed in various ways here. Search the privacy tage.